# c - empirical run-time analysis

Tags: c, runtime, computer-science

hey so im having a bit of a hard time grasping empirical run-time analysis. so i have this question:

Suppose we have an O(1) function that took 8s to execute with n = 2,000. What would you expect the runtime to be if n = 10,000?

now here's my thought process which i believe is wrong: 
if T(n) is O(1) then T(n) = c * O(1) where c is just some constant. so solving for c we get c = T(n) / O(1). now since we know T(2000) = 8s and that n = 2000 we can just plug that in to solve for c, c = (8s) / (2000) which gives us 0.004.
Now we have to the the same for n = 10,000 so in this case T(10,000)= c * O(1)
in this case we can just plug in the same c we found earlier since it just a constant, and plug in 10,000 for O(1) which would gives us T(10,000) = (0.004) * 10,000 which equals 40s. im just not sure if my thought process was right on this one.

Comment: `O(1)` is not a function, you cannot multiply `c` by `O(1)`. `O(f)` is a set of function that behave like `f` (I'm not gonna write the complete definition here without LaTeX, take a look in wikipedia for that). If your `T` in in `O(1)`, then `T(n)` would be (almost always) constant for all n, otherwise it would be in `O(n)`. So for me it makes no sense in comparing `T(2000)` with `T(10000)`. then it would take also around 8s

Comment: Why did you substitute `O(1)` as `2000`? `n` is `2000`, how is `O(1)` related to `n`. Infact `O(1)` is not even a real term. You can't just use it in equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is that we could not expect any particular time.

To say a function’s run-time O(1) is to say there is some number C such that the function always runs in less than C seconds. If the function ran in 8 s once, we know C is at least 8. But it could be a million. Or a septillion.

What O(1) does tell us is that the run time is limited regardless of what n is. That run time could go up and down with various n, but it is always limited by C.

In contrast, compare this to a function with run-time O(n). This means there is a number C such that the function’s run-time is always less than C*n seconds (except a finite number of exceptions are allowed). So we do not have a constant limit; we have a limit that depends on n. This function *might* take more and more time as n grows.

Or it might not. The O notation only tells you a limit on a function’s run-time. It does not tell you the actual run-time. If I know you had a gallon of gas in your car yesterday, and you went 30 miles, I know your car gets at least 30 miles per gallon. If you have two gallons in it today, I know you could go at least 60 miles, but maybe you could go more, and I do not know how far you will actually go. I know there is a limit on your travel, but I do not know what it actually is or how far you will go.

Comment: but wouldnt it be reasonable to *expect* 8s in this case?

Comment: @Jasen no. It took 8s for `n=2000` doesn't mean the constant is `8s`. It could be any number greater than or equal to `8s`.

Comment: statistically speaking there is some *expected value* explain why it is not 8s

Comment: @Jasen Without further information, Eric is right that nothing useful can be said about the expected runtime for other values of `n`. That is to say, it's easy to define functions that make `T(k')` whatever you want it to be given only that `T(k) = c` and `T(n) = O(1)`. You'd need more information about `T` - more data points, guaranteed monotonicity, etc. - to do more than wildly guess. If you want to wildly guess, though, `8s` is not a bad guess given only this information. That is, it is a bad guess, but the information you have is insufficient to make a good guess.

Comment: @Jasen: The statements “The run-time of the function is O(1)” and “The run-time of the function with n = 2000 is 8 seconds” are equivalent to “This car has a finite gas tank” and “This car drove 8 miles yesterday.” From those statements, you cannot tell how far the car will drive tomorrow.

Comment: It's better to say that the function run in less than C *steps* as using a time unit is confusing and not strictly correct. I also find the tank analogy puzzling as in my mind I associate it with a finite travel length while O(1) is more like a finite radius, but that's just me :) Finally, while I generally take the side of pedantry and nitpicking, it is worth noting how in the OP context O(1) is generally understood as constant time (given a set of implict assumptions)

Answer (score 0):

More often than not the problem with [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation is informal (not to say sloppy) notation that carries along a lot of assumption.

First of all, the **Ο** symbol<sup>1</sup> expects a *function* between its parenthesis, so a notation like **Ο**(1) is unclear at first (since 1 is a number).
It is customary in some area of math to denote with "1" the function *f*:ℕ→ℕ defined as *f*(n) = 1 ∀n ∊ ℕ.
This is just a function returning 1 for every input<sup>2</sup>.

Another point to consider is that the  **Ο** as defined classically operates on single-variable functions and to avoid ambiguity the independent variable of the two function should always be explicitly written.
However often this is not done since it is clear from the context that we are dealing with a specific kind of functions only.

For the sake of the reader alertness and at the cost of a cumbersome notation I'll not drop the independent variables thereby writing **Ο**(1) as **Ο**(1(n)).

Finally, I prefer the notation *f*(n) ∊ **Ο**(1(n)) over the common one that uses an equal sign.

---

We have hopefully clarified that with the notation *f*(n) ∊ **Ο**(1(n)) we are asserting a property of a function *f*(n) w.r.t. another function that returns 1 for every input.

The big-O notation is a shorthand (just like the limit notation) that in our specific case translates to

*f*(n) ∊ **Ο**(1(n))

∃N ∊ ℕ:  ∀n > N |*f*(n)| ≤ M · |1(n)|     (by definition)
          ∃N ∊ ℕ:  ∀n > N |*f*(n)| ≤ M · 1(n)       (1(n) always positive)
          ∃N ∊ ℕ:  ∀n > N |*f*(n)| ≤ M · 1           (1(n) = 1 for all n)
          ∃N ∊ ℕ:  ∀n > N |*f*(n)| ≤ M

So the notation simplifies to *f*(n) being bounded in absolute value by an (unspecified!) constants *M*.

This leaves us with *a lot* of functions, even given the value of the function at a point.
For example, even if we know that *f*(2000) = 8, the two functions *g*(n) = 8 cos(n-2000) and *h*(n) = 8 e<sup>n-2000</sup> both are in **Ο**(1(n)) but their value at n = 10000 differs!

---

The big-O notation is useful because it *simplifies* things but so far it seems that it failed by a great length.

The missing piece is that we are dealing with algorithms and their time-complexity<sup>3</sup> so the functions *f* that we are interested in are:

- **Non-piecewise**.
  We consider a piecewise function as arising from two algorithms rather than the expression of a single algorithm.
- **Monotonic non-decreasing**.
  We assume that for the same problem, a bigger instance is lengthier (in time) to solve.

Under this assumptions, we can see that if a function is bounded then at some point it must cease to increase and stay at that value indefinitely.

This is what the  *f*(n) ∊ **Ο**(1(n)) notation expresses: *f* is a constant function (asymptotically).

If *f* is constant then *f*(n) = c and if *f*(2000) = 8 then *c* = 8 and thus *f*(10000) = 8.

At its best the big-O notation is used as follow: take the function between the **Ο**'s parenthesis, multiply it by a constant *c* and use it in place of *f*.

Sometimes we don't even care about constants: **Ο**(1(n)) means that if we double *n* the output stays the same, **Ο**(n) means that if we double *n* the output doubles (n is 2 for n = 2), **Ο**(n<sup>2</sup>) means that if we double *n* the output quadruples (n<sup>2</sup> is 4 for n = 2) and so on.

---

The problem with your approach is two-fold: saying that T(n) = c * O(1) is correct but useless, we made no progress forward since all we are saying is that T(n) is constant multiplied by another constant (remember that O(1) is a constant function) and thus it is a constant.
The other mistake is substituting O(1) with *n* to get the value of *c*.
O(1) is a *set* of functions and even if we write it as *c'* (meaning all the possible constants) this is not *n*! *n* is the input value, the size of the encoding of the problem instance while *c'* is an *arbitrary* constant.

This is the whole point of constant functions: they do not depend on the input, they are *arbitrary* in this regard if you wish.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is not an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) in the strict sense. If we focus our attention to functions defined on a set *C* and *C*-valued (e.g. *f* ∊ *C*→*C*) then **Ο** maps a *C*→*C* function to a *set* of *C*→*C* functions (e.g. **Ο**:(*C*→*C*)→*℘*(*C*→*C*)) and thus is not a map from and to the same set.

<sup>2</sup> The notation is intentionally fuzzy to let the mathematician use it in different contexts; we used it for natural valued sequences but it can be extended to any set and to the meaning of returning the "unity" of any context-implied algebraic structure.

<sup>3</sup> Please beware that run-time is a very very misleading term!

Comment: Nice answer, I don't know why anybody would downvote this one.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo. Maybe something's wrong with it but I'm pretty confident that my reasoning is correct (If I do say so myself).